# Search Box filter in Pagination with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I have created a photo album and a uib-pagination and now I want to add a search box. My pagination consists of 5 pages. The filter that I have used just search the photos which are in that current page.for example if I go to page 10 and want to search a picture which is in page 1 is not working.but it searches and shows me the pictures that are in page 10.
I am wondering which filter should I use to give me the possibility of searching pictures of all pages.

js codes:

```
paintApp.controller('intController', ['$scope','$location','$log', function($scope,$location, $log){

    this.images = [];

    for(i = 1 ; i <51 ; i++){
        this.images.push(i);    
    }

    this.currentPage = 1 ; 
    this.numPerPage = 9 ; 
    this.maxSize = 6;

    this.pageChanged = function() {
        $location.path( "int/"+this.currentPage , false);

    };
}]);

    paintApp.filter('imgThumb', function(){
        return function(images, start){
            return images.slice(start);
        }
    });
```

HTML codes:

```
<div  ng-controller="intController as intCtrl ">   
    <div class="container">
        <uib-pagination 
          ng-model="intCtrl.currentPage"
          total-items="intCtrl.images.length"
          max-size="intCtrl.maxSize"  
          ng-click="intCtrl.pageChanged()"
          >

        </uib-pagination>

        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." name="mySearch" ng-model="search"  >
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" >Go!</button>

                </div><!-- /input-group -->
              </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 uib-pagination"  ng-repeat="img in intCtrl.images | imgThumb:(intCtrl.currentPage -1 )* intCtrl.numPerPage| limitTo:intCtrl.numPerPage | filter: search ">



            <div class="thumbnail ">
                <img  src="src/images/sample{{img}}.jpg" >  
            <div class = "caption"  >
                <h3>{{img}} </h3>
                 <p>
                     <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-primary" role = "button">
                       Button
                     </a> 
                     <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default" role = "button">
                       Button
                     </a>
                 </p>
            </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are first applying the `limitTo` filter, which will yield an array of nine elements, then applying the `filter` filter to that array.

What you want is to first apply the `filter` filter then the `limitTo`, so change the order of the filters:

```
... | filter: search | limitTo:intCtrl.numPerPage
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/wBxVaVCXtgOeBEY3Kh9G?p=preview

Comment: one more point: when I want to search images with single numbers from 0-9 it brings me all images which include these single numbers. how can I write a filter to consider single numbers independent! I mean if I am looking for image "1" it directly shows me that specific image not all the images that have "1" in their numbers!

Comment: Add `true` like this: `| filter:search:true |` to do strict comparison. Note that you need to change your input to type number in your demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/qYfft4lNMKUPlcwLtO5Y?p=preview You can use a variable instead of `true` and change that depending on what you need. Note that you will need someway to handle the case when the input is cleared, since it will not find any results.

Comment: Thanks for your very nice and clear explanations :) Search box does not show images which are in previous pages. If we go to page 3 for example it shows the images in the current page and next pages but not the images in the previous ones like pages 1 or 2 ! and how can I add alert if users write a number of images which does not exist in the array .

Comment: I added another if clause to the onReset function and it works for the alert :this.onReset=function(){
        if(this.search===null) {
            this.search = undefined;
        } if(this.search >45){
            alert('Please select between 1 to 45');
        }     
    };